# using eval to execute jq

Tags: json, bash, while-loop, jq

I'm trying to run a jq filter in a loop, taking the key value that I'm matching from a list in another file.

```
while read line
do
    jqfilter="jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(contains({Tags: [{Key: "Name"}, {Value: "$line"}]}))' describe-instances.json"
    eval "$jqfilter";
done < "./list"
```

The loop is working, `$line` is being substituted with the appropriate value.

The issue is with `{Key: "Name"}`, eval strips the quotes around NAME, and as a result the jq filter does not work.

Comment: Why use eval in the first place? Why don't you invoke jq directly? p.s., note how it's colored in the question, you're trying to place double quotes in a double quoted string, it should be escaped.

Comment: escaping the quotes did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jeff pointed out, it would be advisable to do everything in jq if
possible, but even if a loop cannot be avoided, the eval most definitely can and probably should be, both for efficiency and
to avoid complications.

For example, I suspect you could simply write:

```
jq --arg line "$line" '
  .Reservations[].Instances[]
  | select(contains({Tags: [{Key: "Name"}, {Value: $line}]}))
' describe-instances.json
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you peak, couple of minor edits and your suggestion worked perfectly

`while read line
 do
        jq --arg line "$line" '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(contains({Tags: [{Key: "Name"}, {Value: "line"}]}))' describe-instances.json;
done < "./instances-names"`

Comment: (1) How many top-level entities are there in `describe-instances.json`?  If there's only one, then you can eliminate the `while` loop. (2) The jq filter you show does not include $line and is therefore incorrect.